# Average time between dates in same field by groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, average, datediff

I have a transactional database with sales data and user id like the following:

```
id_usuarioweb   dt_fechaventa
1551415         2015-08-01 14:57:21.737
1551415         2015-08-06 15:34:21.920
6958538         2015-07-30 09:26:24.427
6958538         2015-08-05 09:30:06.247
6958538         2015-08-31 17:39:02.027
39101175        2015-08-05 16:34:17.990
39101175        2015-09-20 20:37:26.043
1551415         2015-09-05 13:41:43.767
3673384         2015-09-06 13:34:23.440
```

And I would like to calculate the average diference between dates by the same customer in the data base (to find average frequency with which the user buys).

I'm aware I can do datediff with two columns, but i'm have issues trying to do it in the same field and "grouping" by user id.

The desired outcome would be like this:

```
id_usuarioweb   avgtime_days
1551415         5
6958538         25
39101175        25
1551415         0
3673384         0
```

How can I achieve this? I would have the database ordered by user_id and then dt_fechaventa (the sale time).

USING: SQL Server 2008

Comment: Why do you have duplicate ids on your result?

Comment: @sstan SQL 2008, added in text

Comment: the expected output is not `average`. what do you exactly need?

Comment: @Lamak they are the same user... purchasing two or three times. There is a unique id for event, but it is not relevant here...

Comment: But you want the average days, so I don't get how you are getting your results if you get duplicated users

Comment: @vkp the expected is average: for example for the first user: 5 days passed between his first and second purchase. For user 6958538: 25 days pass, then another 25 days... the average is 25

Comment: @Lamak it's average BY USER

Comment: EXACTLY, then you should get **one** result per user

Comment: @Lamak sorry, didn't see that in the example, I edited it out

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is calculated like this. Take the maximum and minimum dates, get the difference between them and divide by the number of purchases.

```
SELECT id_usuarioweb, CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(*) < 2
            THEN 0
        ELSE DATEDIFF(dd, 
                MIN(
                    dt_fechaventa
                ), MAX(
                    dt_fechaventa
                )) / (
                COUNT(*) - 
                1
                )
        END AS avgtime_days
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id_usuarioweb
```

EDIT:  (by @GordonLinoff)

The reason that this is correct is easily seen if you look at the math.  Consider three dates, a, b, and c.

The average time between them is:

```
((b - a) + (c - b)) / 2
```

This simplifies to:

```
(c - a) / 2
```

In other words, the intermediate value cancels out.  And, this continues regardless of the number of intermediate values.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the same, because I could have 3 dates, but the average between each one is not necesarilly the same as dividing the max and min.

Comment: @eflores89 . . . The average is the max minus the min divided by one less than the count.  This is the easiest and best way to calculate that value.

Comment: yup, this is actually the simplest way

Comment: you're right. Didn't realize the -1 ... this is much simpler

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_usuarioweb ORDER BY dt_fechaventa),
            N  = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY id_usuarioweb)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT  A.id_usuarioweb,
        AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY,A.dt_fechaventa,B.dt_fechaventa)) avgtime_days
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN CTE B
    ON A.id_usuarioweb = B.id_usuarioweb
    AND A.RN = B.RN - 1
WHERE A.N > 1
GROUP BY A.id_usuarioweb;
```

I'm filtering the users that only have one row there, because you can't calculate an average of days with them.

[**Here is a demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7db63/2) in sqlfiddle of this. And the results are:

```
╔═══════════════╦══════════════╗
║ id_usuarioweb ║ avgtime_days ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║       1551415 ║           17 ║
║       6958538 ║           16 ║
║      39101175 ║           46 ║
╚═══════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Comment: Yep! Brilliant! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can first number rows using `row_number` and then do a `self-join` with the `cte`. Then perform the `average`. However, you would get one row per user, but not as per the expected result.

```
with x as 
(select id_usuarioweb, dt_fechaventa,
row_number() over(partition by id_usuarioweb order by dt_fechaventa) as rn
from tablename)
select x1.id_usuarioweb, avg(datediff(dd,x1.dt_fechaventa,x2.dt_fechaventa)) as avgdiff
from x x1 join x x2 
on x1.id_usuarioweb = x2.id_usuarioweb and x1.rn = x2.rn-1
group by x1.id_usuarioweb
```

Comment: there's no `lag` in SQL Server 2008

Comment: changed it to exclude `lag`